# What are the pitfalls in the approach to calculate time diff

Tags: php

I wish to calculate the difference b/w 2 times in min:sec format . so is my approch correct

```
date("i:s",(strtotime($User['end_time']) - strtotime($User['start_time'])));
```

Comment: If you are getting your desiring output than it is correct :)

Comment: yes i am getting it but are there any pitfalls

Comment: No I don't think so, your way is correct !!

Comment: @RikeshShah i didn't get what u mean. Am i right or wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the problems with timezones on some servers.

A bettter way would be using UTC timezone for calculation:

```
$date = new DateTime('', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime($User['end_time']) - strtotime($User['start_time'])); 
echo $date->format('i:s');
```

Another thing, if they are different in exactly 1 hour, the result will be 00:00

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime($User['end_time']) - strtotime($User['start_time'])` gives you the difference in seconds. Then you pass it to `date`, so you get the minute and second of the date whose unix timestamp is that.